# Pervasive 8.x how to access? Where to find

Tags: database, csv, data-conversion, pervasive

I am working on some data conversion. I asked for files in csv format but client didn't know how to convert and instead handed me a folder with bunch of *.btr files and FIELD.DDF, FILE.DDF, INDEX.DDF and USER.DDF.

My question is how to access them and essentially convert them into csv file format so my ETL tool can read those CSV/TXT files.

After some messing around I have figured out these were made using Pervasive 8.7 which is not supported and I can't find any demo workgroup or server download. On top of it I found some pervasive data tools but when I try to download them I get the message that tools can only work on Windows XP or earlier.

I am confused as to how to proceed. Is there any alternatives instead of going back and accessing client system and trying to convert these files into CSV using clients comp?

BTW I also have a Pervasive 8.7 client software in the data folder but when I try to run it seems to execute and then closes without any error. I tried changing the compatibility level as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a Pervasive.SQL engine in order to access the files.  PSQL v8 (and v9 and v10) are unsupported.  The current version is PSQL v11 and a trial version can be downloaded at http://pervasivedb.com/psqlv11/pages/default.aspx.  PSQL v11 can read and write PSQL v8.x files without
Once you have an engine installed and running,  you should be able to create an ODBC DSN pointing to the DDFs and data files (BTR files).  Once you have an ODBC DSN, you can use any of your favorite tools to export the data to CSV.  PSQL v11 even has an "Export Data" option if you right click the table within the Pervasive Control Center.
Just curious, what tools did you find that are for xP or earlier?

Comment: +1, everywhere I have searched found the answers by you, I admire your knowledge and authenticity on Pervasive. Thanks for being a great resource. I will share the link but I have to search it again in bit a hurry at the moment so will share with you soon. Thanks a TON!

Comment: Glad to help.  I feel that if I have the knowledge and someone else needs it, why not share it.  Good luck with your conversion.  Post up if you have problems or need other help.  No problem on the link.  I was more curious than anything else.